Connect Sony HT-S20R to Windows and disable front speakers
I have Sony HT-S20R 5.1 sound system. It has HDMI ARC (currently connected to TV), 3mm audio and SPDIF jack (connected to laptop)
My desk is very close to front speakers and it's very annoying to listen to music when I am just 1 feet away. So I want to disable front speakers and listen music in only rear speakers. But when I watch TV, I need 5.1 channel sound.
Currently, I manually eject the cable for front speaker when I work on my desk. And plug it in again when I was watch TV. I feel it's not good idea long-term as I might damage the speaker by doing this constantly.
I have tried everything including buying this sound card; CSL - USB 7.1 Sound Card External - 7.1 Surround Sound - Stereo Audio Adapter. But I only saw 2.0 channel in windows sound settings.
I was hoping to see all 5.1 channel in Windows sound settings using these solutions. But windows only only shows 2.0 channel. If windows had shown 5.1 channel, I would have set volume of front speakers to 0.
Any solution?

But nothing works... You need to be more specific. What were you expecting to happen with the external sound card, what exactly you tried and what were the results?

@ChanganAuto Updated.

That means the external sound card is the one doing the processing (or isn't a true 7.1). In any case you should have those option when using any digital connection (e.g. S/PDIF)

Here is how I solved the problem:

My speaker has the feature. If I turn it off, the back speakers and center channels stop working. But I wanted to stop the front speaker and center channel instead.
So, I replaced the physical pins for the front and back speakers in the back panel of the woofer.
Now when I turn off this setting, it turns off front speakers and center channel instead.
